# Using a Temp Table in a Dynamic Pivot

Tags: sql-server, pivot, unpivot

I am trying to use a temp table inside of a dynamic pivot query. I have read that the procedure will not work because the temp table is outside of the scope even though it is a global table. This is strange to me because it works in sql fiddle but not in SQL Server 2012. How can I edit my query so that it gives me an output other than (xxx row(s) affected)?

Here is my query:

```
SELECT         cc.CaseCaseId AS CaseId, cc.Label AS CaseName, rce.EcoDate,  cc.OperatorName, cc.State, cc.County, ei.IROR,  rce.NDCash
into ##Temp2
FROM            PhdRpt.ReportCaseList_542 AS rcl INNER JOIN
                         CaseCases AS cc ON rcl.CaseCaseId = cc.CaseCaseId INNER JOIN
                         PhdRpt.RptCaseEco_542 AS rce ON rcl.ReportRunCaseId = rce.ReportRunCaseId INNER JOIN
                         PhdRpt.EcoIndicators_542 AS ei ON rcl.ReportRunCaseId = ei.ReportRunCaseId


DECLARE @colsPivot AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
 @colsUnpivot as NVARCHAR(MAX),
 @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @colsPivot = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(EcoDate) 
 from ##Temp2
 FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
 ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
 ,1,1,'')

select @colsUnpivot = stuff((select ','+quotename(C.name)
 from sys.columns as C
 where C.object_id = object_id('##Temp2') and
 C.name LIKE 'NDCash%'
 for xml path('')), 1, 1, '')


set @query 
 = 'select *
 from
 (
 select cc.CaseCaseId AS CaseId, cc.Label AS CaseName, rce.EcoDate,  cc.OperatorName, cc.State, cc.County, ei.IROR, val, col
FROM          ##Temp2  
 unpivot
 (
 val
 for col in ('+ @colsunpivot +')
 ) u
 ) x1
 pivot
 (
 max(val)
 for EcoDate in ('+ @colspivot +')
 ) p'

exec(@query)


Drop table ##Temp2
```

Here is the table structure:

```
CaseId       EcoDate          NDCash
2         2003-01-01    26.6384943638238
2         2004-01-01    23.9534867373416
2         2005-01-01    25.9197356158675
2         2006-01-01    25.3280437702064
2         2007-01-01    24.9828609298022
2         2008-01-01    26.4019321789285
2         2009-01-01    26.6384943638238
2         2010-01-01    24.0660715481002
2         2011-01-01    26.6384943638238
2         2012-01-01    22.5718444448345
2         2013-01-01    26.6384943638238
```

Comment: A more immediate problem with using a ##global temp table at all is that this effectively limits concurrency to 1. What do you think happens when two users run this code at the same time?

Comment: @AaronBertrand what do you suggest as a solution? I am new at SQL so any advice is appreciated.

Comment: I haven't even tried to digest your problem. I just know that global ##temp table is very rarely the right solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I am missing something, you don't need to use `UNPIVOT` for this and you don't need to use a temp table, just query the data directly. It looks like your current query is only unpivoting one column which is not needed. You use unpivot to convert multiple columns into multiple rows.

You should be able to use:

```
DECLARE @colsPivot AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
 @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @colsPivot = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(rce.EcoDate) 
                             from PhdRpt.RptCaseEco_542 AS rce
                             group by rce.EcoDate
                             order by rce.EcoDate
                     FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                     ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
                     ,1,1,'')

set @query 
 = 'select *
 from
 (
     SELECT cc.CaseCaseId AS CaseId, 
        cc.Label AS CaseName, 
        rce.EcoDate,  
        cc.OperatorName, 
        cc.State, 
        cc.County, 
        ei.IROR,  
        rce.NDCash
    FROM PhdRpt.ReportCaseList_542 AS rcl 
    INNER JOIN CaseCases AS cc 
        ON rcl.CaseCaseId = cc.CaseCaseId 
    INNER JOIN PhdRpt.RptCaseEco_542 AS rce 
        ON rcl.ReportRunCaseId = rce.ReportRunCaseId 
    INNER JOIN PhdRpt.EcoIndicators_542 AS ei 
        ON rcl.ReportRunCaseId = ei.ReportRunCaseId
 ) x1
 pivot
 (
     max(NDCash)
     for EcoDate in ('+ @colspivot +')
 ) p'

exec(@query)
```

Comment: Thank you very much bluefeet. If there were another column, let's say "Discounted" and I wanted them both to be pivoted, would I then have to use the unpivot?

Comment: Yes when you have multiple columns to pivot, then you need to unpivot.

Comment: @RolandP (And this is why you don't "dumb down" or simplify your problem - people end up solving the simpler problem, leaving you with questions and further problems to solve.)

Comment: @AaronBertrand Thank you for the advice. I was trying to simplify it so that you may see what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: @bluefeet I have added in the unpivot and added a second C.Name like ' ' to my query and I get the error "The column "NetGas" is specified multiple times in the column list of the UNPIVOT operator." DO you know why I would be getting this error?

Answer (score 0):

change the exec(@query) to sp_executeSQl @query.

exec(@query) will not execute in the current context, but where as the sp_executeSQL will execute with the current context that includes the temporary tables as well.

Comment: Why do you think one of these methods works in the same context, but the other doesn't? No problems here: `CREATE TABLE #x(i INT);INSERT #x SELECT 1;EXEC('SELECT i FROM #x;');EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT i FROM #x;';DROP TABLE #x;`

Comment: @Surendra Nath GM I have changed it and it still does not execute.